# Why is my css text is only 1 line and overflowing?

Tags: html, css

```css
@-webkit-keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink-caret {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}

h1 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  width: 335px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font: bold 300% Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
  border-right: .1em solid black;
  width: 1000.5em;
  margin: 2em 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: typing 30s steps(2001, end), blink-caret 5s step-end infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vestibulum lectus ut lacus scelerisque dapibus. Fusce sed purus augue. Aenean massa nunc, efficitur semper eros ut, maximus malesuada neque. Fusce in lorem et tellus ultrices porttitor. Aenean
    egestas, sapien a elementum fringilla, nibh tortor vestibulum ex, vel maximus tortor lorem quis mauris.</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

**Sorry, I am a newbie and I don't know why is it overflowing. Can someone help me to stop that? I tried to display inline-block and a few other things that I found on the internet but nothing worked**

Comment: your issue is with your css` width` is defined twice, also your css animation code is wrong, fix it and it will work correctly

Comment: width should be 100% and not 100.5em

Comment: Your width is 1000.5em. Try to use 100% that should solve one of the problems.

Comment: Your `font-size: 300%` plus the second `width: 1000.5em` create a total `<h1>` element width of `16 * 3 * 1000.5 =  48024px`. The text fits that width, hence no wrapping...
=> 16px is the default font-size for a webpage in most browsers, 1em = 1*parent-font-size-width => 1em = 16px so 300% of that would be 48px.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you have `width` defined twice - the second one being `width: 1000.5em;` which is much wider than the screen.  Remove that.

The text won't wrap if you have `white-space` set to `nowrap;`.  Remove that rule as well.  That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `width:100%` instead of 1000.5em.

```css
h1 {
  overflow: hidden; 
  border-right: .1em solid black;
  font: bold 300% Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
    blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vestibulum lectus ut lacus scelerisque dapibus. Fusce sed purus augue. Aenean massa nunc, efficitur semper eros ut, maximus malesuada neque. Fusce in lorem et tellus ultrices porttitor. Aenean
    egestas, sapien a elementum fringilla, nibh tortor vestibulum ex, vel maximus tortor lorem quis mauris.</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Heçkır 001 If this answers your question please consider giving it a tick mark ✔ it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla CSS

- uses the last error free defined property in a rule when the property is entered more than once in the same rule
- uses the browser font-size settings as default for `html/root font-size`, which is usually `16px` in most browsers
- `em` uses the parent `font-size` as multiplier

`width` is defines twice in your `h1 { ... }`, so the final width used will be `1000.5em`.

Doing the calculations for the total element width:

`300%` of `default 16px font-size` times `1000.5em` yields a `48024px` for the total element width at `font-size: 48px`

The given `<h1>` text fits the calculated width, hence no wrapping will occur. For reference a regular desktop computer has 1920px viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the `whitespace:nowrap` property in your CSS file. It converts the text into a single line causing overflow of the text. I hope it helps!